# Python regex: validate mobile numbers from Germany and Austria

Tags: python, regex, match

I have worked on a regex which matches German and Austrian mobile numbers. I was not able to complete it.

This is what I have so far:

```
[^\d]((\+49|0049|0|\+43|0043)\s?(1|9)[1567]\d{1,2}([ \-/]*\d){7,8})(?!\d)
```

You can check the performance in my [regex-demo](https://regex101.com/r/hpmJwL/1).

- The international dialing code begins with `+49` for Germany and `+43` for Austria. This is covered in my regex.
- The length of the mobile numbers varies on the way you write the phone number. I collected multiple examples [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hpmJwL/1).

**Question:** How to improve the regex in order to match all examples of my demo?

Furthermore, I want to check if a specific number matches the defined regex.
However, my approach doen't really work:

```
import re
slot_value = "0176 48200179"
regex_mobile = r"[^\d]((\+49|0049|0|\+43|0043)\s?(1|9)[1567]\d{1,2}([ \-/]*\d){7,8})(?!\d)" 

match = re.fullmatch(regex_mobile, slot_value)
print(match)

>>> None
```

Comment: I need more explication for your issue. You want to match only number for germany and Austria. For valid germany number : +49 , 0049, + (49) and for austria : +43, 0043 ? is it right ?

Comment: Correct. Germany +49 , 0049, + (49). Austria: +43 , 0043, + (43). Without international number: ``0``

Comment: Recommend to first remove parenthesis and stuff (normalize string), which will either make the pattern shorter and also your life much easier when parsing such stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be asserting 10-12 digits after matching the first part of the pattern with the variations of the `+` and the parenthesis.

Note that you can write `(1|9)` as `[19]` and if you don't need the capture group value, you can omit the parenthesis and at the beginning of the pattern you might also shorten the alternatives using a character class as well like `4[39]|004[39]`

I have started the pattern with an anchor `^` as your pattern starts with `[^\d]` that actually consumes a character.

```
^(?:\+4[39]|004[39]|0|\+\(49\)|\(\+49\))\s?(?=(?:[^\d\n]*\d){10,12}(?!\d))(\()?[19][1567]\d{1,2}(?(1)\))\s?\d(?:[ /-]?\d)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rj1puZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match all numbers, when :

- Germany number are : +49 , 0049, +(49)
- Austria number are : +43 , 0043, +(43)

Your Regex will be :

```
.*(?:\+49|0049|\+\(49\)|\+43|0043|\+\(43\)).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HccxNW/1)

You can use [finditer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-we-use-re-finditer-method-in-Python-regular-expression) to find all numbers.

Below an example:

```
import re

regex = r".*(?:\+49|0049|\+\(49\)|\+43|0043|\+\(43\)).*"

test_str = ("################################### This is allowed ##########################\n"
    "+49 15207930698\n"
    "+49 15207955279\n"
    "+49 1739341284\n"
    "+49 1626589266\n\n"
    "+49915175461907\n"
    "+4915207930698\n"
    "+491635556416\n"
    "017687400179\n"
    "015903900297\n"
    "015175355164\n"
    "015175354885\n"
    "01771789427\n\n"
    "+49 915175461907\n"
    "+43 915175461907\n"
    "+49159039012341\n"
    "+43159039012341\n"
    "+4915207829969\n"
    "+4917697400179\n"
    "+4915903904567\n"
    "+4915902944599\n"
    "+4915902944599\n"
    "+4915903904567\n"
    "+491739341284\n"
    "+431739341284\n\n"
    "+49 176 97 456 123\n"
    "0176 79 123 17 9\n"
    "0176 97 50 01 79\n"
    "0176 79 123 179\n"
    "0174 80123179\n\n"
    "0049 915175461907\n"
    "0043 915175461907\n"
    "0049159039012341\n"
    "0043159039012341\n"
    "004915207829969\n\n"
    "(+49) 17697123456\n"
    "+(49) (1739) 34 12 84\n"
    "+49 (1739) 34-12-84\n\n"
    "############################################################################################\n"
    "################################### This is NOT allowed ####################################\n"
    "012345678901234\n"
    "123w345345345345\n"
    "0123456789101191919\n\n"
    "### Too short\n"
    "+49 15902\n"
    "+49 1590123\n"
    "+49 15903567\n"
    "+49 177178796\n"
    "+49 757130309\n\n"
    "+4915902\n"
    "+491590123\n"
    "+4915903567\n"
    "+49177178796\n"
    "+49757130309\n\n"
    "### Too long\n"
    "+49 1590345985412\n"
    "+491590345985412\n\n"
    "### Not German and not Austrain format\n"
    "+12127319863\n"
    "+13322014056\n"
    "+12126712234\n"
    "+427532697710\n"
    "+417868150810\n"
    "+287533002875\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I see 2 problems with you regex: 1) It matches with numbers who are to short to be valid. 2) It doens't match with numbers who do not provide internation code. These numbers start simply with a ``0``. I provided some examples in my demo. Apart from that you approach looks promissing!